# Alternative To READ UNCOMMITED With FOR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, transactions, isolation-level

We have 2 scripts/mysql connections that are grabbing rows from a table.  Once a script grabs some rows, the other script must not be able to access those rows.

What I've got so far, that seems to work is this:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
START TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM table WHERE result='new' FOR UPDATE

// Loop over update
UPDATE table SET result='old' WHERE id=...

COMMIT
```

From what I understand the same connection could read the dirty data, but the other connections shouldn't be able to since the rows are locked.  Is this correct?

Also is there a better way of guaranteeing that each row can only be `SELECT` one time with both scripts running?

edit:
Oh... and the engine is Innodb

edit: Also I'd like to try to avoid deadlocks, unless they really have no effect, in which I could just prepare for them and rerun the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT ... FOR UDATE` sets exclusive lock on the rows, and if it's not possible it waits for lock to be released, the main aim of `SELECT ... FOR UDATE` statement is to prevent others from reading the certain rows, while you are manipulating them.

If I get your question right, by 'dirty data' you mean those locked rows?
Don't see why you call them 'dirty', cause they are just locked, but indeed inside of same transaction you can read the rows you've locked (obviuosly).

Regarding your second question

> Also is there a better way of guaranteeing that each row can only be
>   SELECT one time with both scripts running?

`SELECT ... FOR UDATE` guarantees that in each moment certain rows can be read only inside of one transaction. I dont see a better way to do so, as soon as this statement was specially designed for that purpose.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the initial question that I'd like to avoid deadlocks too... that's why the use of `READ UNCOMMITED`.  Is it silly to worry about deadlocks and just prepare for them ahead of time?

Comment: I dont see any reason to worry about deadlocks yet. Possibly I dont see the whole situation...